# What does "spokes" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

As far as I know and have checked a [few](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoke) [dictionaries](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/spoke) and done some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=spoke%20meaning&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIR503IR503&oq=spoke%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4161j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), *spoke* is either a verb, past tense of *speak*, or a noun which has a few meanings such as the metal bars on a bicycle wheel; plus a few other meanings that are less frequently used. However none of them make sense in the following sentence from [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolute_Support_Mission#Objectives_and_deployment):

> The Resolute Support Mission envisages the deployment of approximately
>   12,000 personnel from NATO and partner nations in Afghanistan with the
>   central hub at Kabul and Bagram Airfield supporting four ***spokes***.

What does the word mean in the sentence above?

Comment: You linked a definition from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoke) - please reread definition 1.b. and visualize a central hub with radiating *spokes* or logistical routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the 'Airfield' in your sentence indicates that this is probably meant in the [Airline Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_hub) sense, which is a specific implementation of [the spoke-hub distribution paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoke%E2%80%93hub_distribution_paradigm).

[image]

In the above diagram, Denver is a hub; Los Angeles is another hub.  Both have spokes radiating from them.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of "metal bars on a bicycle wheel" is correct.

The article is using a wheel symbolically. Picture Kabul/Bagram Airfield centrally located (the bicycle hub) with **spokes** radiating out from the hub.

Comment: Actually this goes back several thousand years earlier than bicycles. The classical [spoked wagon/chariot wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel#/media/File:Greek_chariot.jpg) had a hub and perhaps 8 spokes going out to the rim.